Inquiry About the Nyström Method and Matrix Inversion
I have been studying the Nyström method for obtaining low-rank approximations of matrices and would like to inquire about its applicability in calculating the inverse of a matrix.
In my research, I came across the following article: Nyström approximation. However, I am unclear about how the authors applied the Woodbury identity to compute the inverse in this context.
I understood up to equation (1)
\begin{align} K = K_{22} &= K_{21} U_1 \underbrace{\Lambda^{-1} \Lambda}_{I} \Lambda^{-1} U_1^\top K_{12} \\ &= K_{21} U_1 \Lambda^{-1} U_1^\top K_{12}. \tag{1} \label{eq:K22} \end{align}
After that, I am not able to follow: how to calculate $K^{-1}$ using Woodbury identity.
\begin{align} K^{-1} = K_{22}^{-1} = K_{21} U_1 \underbrace{(\Lambda + U_1^\top K_{12} K_{21} U_1)^{-1}}_{m \times m} U_1^\top K_{12}. \end{align}
Could someone please assist me in understanding this aspect?
Additionally, I would appreciate any insights into alternative approaches for calculating the matrix inverse using the Nyström approximation.
Thank you for your assistance.

I would use it as follows. First, assume that $K\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ is of rank $r$ where $r<<p$. Let's pick $B=\Lambda^{-1}$, $C=K_{21}U_1$ to write:
$$
(\epsilon I + K_{21}U_1\Lambda^{-1}U_1^\top K_{12})^{-1} = (\epsilon I + CBC^\top)^{-1},
$$
where $\epsilon$ is a very small constant, e.g. added for stability. As $\epsilon\to 0$ this quantity approaches $K^{-1}$, yet requires inverting an $p\times p$ matrix. At this point we invoke the Woodbury identity:
$$
\begin{align}
(A + CBC^\top)^{-1}&={A}^{-1}-{A}^{-1} {C}\left({B}^{-1}+{C}^{\top} {A}^{-1} {C}\right)^{-1} {C}^{\top} {A}^{-1}\\
&=\frac1{\epsilon}I-\frac1{\epsilon^2} C\left(B^{-1}+\frac1{\epsilon}C^{\top} C\right)^{-1} C^{\top}\\
&=\frac1{\epsilon}I-\frac1{\epsilon^2} K_{21}U_1\left(\Lambda+\frac1{\epsilon}U_1^{\top}K_{12} K_{21}U_1\right)^{-1} U_1^\top K_{12},
\end{align}
$$
where $A=\epsilon I_p$ and we frequently used $K_{12} =K_{21}^\top$ (and vice versa) to eliminate the transpositions. Notice that the only inversion required in the last equation is of size $r\times r$. This seems to correspond to some parts of the identity that you mentioned but I'm not sure if they are the same up to some approximation. Essentially what I have here is $(\epsilon I+K)^{-1}$ and only for some small $\epsilon$, it recovers $K^{-1}$.
This trick can be understood from the perspective of regularized Hessians, but I will not delve into the details here. Some further information can be found at Singh et al. [*].
[*] Singh, Dinesh, Hardik Tankaria, and Makoto Yamada. "Nys-newton: Nystr" om-approximated curvature for stochastic optimization." arXiv preprint (2021). https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.08577.

The Woodbury identity is a useful tool for updating the inverse of a matrix when a rank-k update is applied. It states that for a matrix A and a rank-k matrix E,
(A + E)^-1 = A^-1 - A^-1 E (I + E^T A^-1 E)^-1 E^T A^-1
In the context of the Nyström approximation, we have:
K = K22 + K21 U1 Λ^-1 U1^T K12
Here, K22 is the submatrix of K corresponding to the sampled rows and columns, K21 and K12 are the off-diagonal submatrices, U1 is the matrix of eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues in Λ, and Λ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues.
We can apply the Woodbury identity to calculate K^-1 as follows:
K^-1 = (K22 + K21 U1 Λ^-1 U1^T K12)^-1
= K22^-1 - K22^-1 K21 U1 (I + Λ^-1 U1^T K12 K22^-1 K21 U1)^-1 U1^T K12 K22^-1
To compute the inverse in the Woodbury identity, we need to invert the matrix I + Λ^-1 U1^T K12 K22^-1 K21 U1. This is a smaller matrix than K, and it can be inverted more efficiently using standard techniques.
Once we have the inverse of this matrix, we can substitute it back into the Woodbury identity to obtain K^-1.

I didn't follow this line : K = K22 + K21 U1 Λ^-1 U1^T K12
In the article it is mentioned as: K = K22 = K21 U1 Λ^-1 U1^T K12
